# How can I install node-red offline

Tags: node-red

I have already installed node.js in my windows machine. Now, I want to install node-red but I don't have internet connection.

I have a separate machine with internet connection and I have successfully installed node-red using the command below:

npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red

I have read some forums that I can just zip my installed files from machine 1 then copy it to my offline machine. However, it did not work for me, I suspect probably because I had it installed globally.

Thank you.

Comment: It definitely would be best to install everything into a local directory before trying to zip the whole lot, and copy it to the 2nd machine. So when you say "it did not work", what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you @SteveR for your reply. When I ran node-red in cmd, it seems everything is fine saying it starting flows. But in my web, it is empty. Nothing is displayed, no nodes in the left side.

Comment: If the console log shows no errors, then the next place to look is in the browsers dev console -- use F12 to open it and see if there are any javascript errors shown when you reload the node-red editor page.

Comment: @SteveR, I just tried it using another browser and it works. Thanks for your inputs anyway, really appreciate it.

Comment: Aryah, if a different browser works, then it's likely that the original browser's cache was not in synch with the new code you copied over. Clearing cache or forcing a reload (or several!) should get the first browser working again...